# How to load Highcharts using Webpack

Tags: javascript, highcharts, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I'm using Highcharts lib component of V5.0.10

```
highcharts.min.js
highcharts.more.min.js
highcharts.prototype-adapter.min.js
```

and I'm importing them in my lib.js which is entry point for webpack.config.js

```
require('../customLibs/highcharts/js/highcharts.min.js');
require('../customLibs/highcharts/js/highcharts.more.min.js');
require('../customLibs/highcharts/js/highcharts.prototype-adapter.min.js');
```

Here is my Webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var config = {
    entry: [
        'angular',
        './src/lib.js',
        './src/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'mcdist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
},
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=images/',
    }, {
        test: /\.css|scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: ['css-loader', "sass-loader"]
        })
    }, {
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: [
            path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.html')
        ],
        use: [
            { loader: 'ngtemplate-loader?relativeTo=' + (path.resolve(__dirname, './src')) },
            { loader: 'html-loader' },
        ]
    }],
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Demo',
        minify: {
            collapseWhitespace: true,
        },
        cache: true,
        hash: true,
        inject: true,
        filename: './index.html',
        template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: "app.css",
        disable: false,
        allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        Holder: 'holderjs',
        moment: 'moment',
        loadash: 'loadash.min',
    })

],  
devServer: {
    proxy: [{
        context: [
            '/mcdist/api',
            '/mcdist/appConfig',
            '/mcdist/logout',
            '/mcaid/j_spring_security_logout'
        ],
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        secure: false
    }],
    port: 9000
},
};

module.exports = config;
```

but I'm getting '**ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined**' when JS file referring to Highcharts loads up.

Can you please suggest correct way to load Highcharts with Webpack and load them in application to use ?

Comment: Creating an array of entry points is not a good way for the files which are dependent on each other. You can create one entry point and then when you need highcharts, require it in the specific files. If you want to split you bundle file, create an object like it is describe in the webpack docs: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#separate-app-and-vendor-entries